# Searchlogic Limit

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I pass a search limit on searchlogic....

```
user = User.name_like("John")
```

... and limit the search to 50 results?

I have a User almost 3,000+ and base on New Relic(Application Tracking) it takes too much memory in the server. I would like to limit the search to 50 for it to not search through all users.

Answer (score 1):

```
user = User.name_like("John").limit(50)
```

or make use of other gems such as will_paginate? (i.e. returning the first page which contains 50 results)

Comment: It dosen't seem to work. Im usring rails 2.3.5
here is my exact code:
@search = Enrollment.name_like(params[:name]).studid_like(params[:name]).semester_id_equals(params[:semester]).limit(20)

Comment: have you tried to inspect what is the sql generated? I would try it out later to figure out the problem...

Comment: I have used will_paginate but there was no difference in server memory.